# Can't use brew version PHP

Tags: macos, php, homebrew

Here's my .profile

[image]

And here's what happens when I run php.

[image]

Am I missing something? Did I do something wrong in my profile? How come when I run the php command my OS X runs the system PHP instead? But when I run which php it clearly points to the homebrew location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a wild guess, can you try

**cp ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile**

**source $HOME/.bash_profile**

if problem persists, can you post your **echo $PATH** result for further troubleshooting?

Comment: I did source my .profile last time, didn't work. After I read your answer I ran source again on my .profile. Now this time it works. Weird....